# How to use Intel's Math function library with gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, libm

I am trying the following:
`gcc -o foo foo.c -L /path/to/directory/containing/libimf.so -limf`
and I have used 'log2' function in foo.c. I want it to link with Intel optimized library function but I am getting the following error

`/usr/bin/ld: skipping /path/to/libimf.so when searching for -limf`

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -limf`

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong `libimf.so` for the linking. There were two different `libimf.so` at two different locations corresponds to [Intel MIC](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/many-integrated-core/intel-many-integrated-core-architecture.html) and Intel IA64 architecture. It worked with correct one(IA-64).

Answer (score -1):

Argument -L expects a directory, not a file.

Comment: It is directory path containing libimf.so. I edited the description.